# Prove that $e^a e^b = e^{a+b}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I've read the argument in Rudin, but I think I need a little clarification

\begin{align}
e^a e^b &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{k!} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{b^m}{m!}\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ n!}{n!}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a^k}{k!} \frac{b^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a+b)^n}{n!}\\
&=e^{a+b}\\
\end{align}

I'd like to understand how we get from the first line to the second. Of course $m =n-k$, but how do we ensure that we haven't missed any addends in the limit changing process?

Changing limits: $m=0 \rightarrow n-k=0 \rightarrow k=n$ and $m=\infty \rightarrow n-k=\infty \rightarrow k=0$, assuming $n \to \infty$.

\begin{align}
\frac{b^m}{m!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{k!} 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{k!} \frac{b^{m}}{m!} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{?} \frac{a^k}{k!} \frac{b^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
\end{align}

how to justify that "?"$=n$ ?

Comment: This is an application of the Cauchy product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have two series

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$$

$$q(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_kx^k$$

Then multiplying and collecting terms gives $$(p\cdot q)(x)=a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+b_1a_0)x+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2)x^2+\dots \\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j+i=k}a_jb_i\right)x^k\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_jb_{k-j}\right)x^k$$

[This informal approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) actually [works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem) whenever either one of the series converges and the other converges absolutely. Try to see what happens when we choose the series to be those of $e^a,e^b$.

**ADD** The case when the series are not power series, but just plain series gives
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {{a_j}} {b_{k - j}}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{a_k}}  \cdot \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{b_k}} $$

This gives when $$\eqalign{
  & {a_k} = \frac{{{a^k}}}{{k!}}  \cr 
  & {b_k} = \frac{{{b^k}}}{{k!}} \cr} $$ that

$$\displaylines{
  {e^a}{e^b} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {\frac{{{a^j}}}{{j!}}} \frac{{{b^{k - j}}}}{{\left( {k - j} \right)!}}} \right)}  \cr 
   = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k!}}\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^k {\frac{{k!}}{{j!\left( {k - j} \right)!}}{a^j}} {b^{k - j}}} \right)}  \cr 
   = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k!}}{{\left( {a + b} \right)}^k}}  \cr 
   = {e^{a + b}} \cr} $$

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you're not thinking of this right. Think about taking the first quadrant in $mk$-space and filling it up with (anti-)diagonal lines $n=k+m=\text{constant}$. As you  let $n$ vary from $1$ to $\infty$, you hit every $(m,k)$.